# doc.data(); from firebase returns undefined but prints normally?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, return, undefined

So I need to get data with a given id from a firebase collection. My function then should return it (the document) and in my test it should print (as the 'result'). For some reason, my test prints 'undefined' but my function (getIteration(id)) prints out exactly what I need it to return (at the console.log above the return). Why is it returning undefined but with the same doc.data() printing exactly what I need?

Here is my code:

```
//gets the iteration with the given id
async function getIteration(id) {
    fb.db.collection('iteration').where('id', '==', id).get().then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.data())
            return doc.data();
        })
    })
}
```

and my test:

```
firebase.getIteration(fbIterationID).then(function(result){
 console.log('LOGGING FB ITERATION DOCUMENT WITH THE ID OF: ' + fbIterationID)
    console.log(result)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //gets the iteration with the given id
async function getIteration(id) {
    return fb.db.collection('iteration').where('id', '==', id).get().then(snapshot => {
        return snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
    })
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the promise from `getIteration` so the caller can use its results.  Making the function async isn't going to do that for you:

```
async function getIteration(id) {
    return fb.db...
}
```

Comment: Like this? This still gives me undefined :(

`async function getIteration(id) {
   return fb.db.collection('iteration').where('id', '==', id).get().then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.data())
            return doc.data();
        })
    })
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { Avatar } from 'react-native-elements/dist/avatar/Avatar';
import CustomListItem from '../../components/CustomListItem'
import { auth, db } from '../../services/firebase';
import {SimpleLineIcons} from '@expo/vector-icons'


export default function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {

    const [chats, setChats] = useState([]);
    const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState([])
    const [isDms, setIsDms] = useState(true);
    
  

    

    useEffect(() => {
        function unsubscribeDms(){ 
            db.collection('chats').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                if (doc.data().isDM == true){
                    if (doc.data().users[0] == auth.currentUser.uid){
                        setChats(chats => [...chats, {id: doc.id, data: doc.data(), otherUser: doc.data().users[1]}])

                        db.collection("users").doc(doc.data().users[1]).get().then((doc) => {
                            setUserInfo(userInfo => [...userInfo, {uid: doc.id,  data: doc.data()}]
                                )
                        
                            
                        })
                        
                    }

                    else if (doc.data().users[1] == auth.currentUser.uid){
                        
                        setChats(chats => [...chats, {id: doc.id, data: doc.data(), otherUser: doc.data().users[0]}])

                        db.collection("users").doc(doc.data().users[0]).get().then((doc) => {
                            setUserInfo(userInfo => [...userInfo, {uid: doc.id,  data: doc.data()}]
                            )
                        
                            
                        })
                    }
                }

            })


            
        })}


        async function unsubscribeGcs(){
            await db.collection('chats').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
                snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                    if (doc.data().isDM == false){
                        var allUsers  = doc.data().users
                        if (allUsers.includes(auth.currentUser.uid)){
                            setChats(chats => [...chats, {id: doc.id, data: doc.data()}])

                        }
                    }
                })
            })
        }

        if (isDms){
            unsubscribeDms()

        }

        else {
            unsubscribeGcs()
        }

        

        

    }, [])

    function getphotoUrl(uid){

        //return JSON.stringify(userInfo[0])


        return userInfo.length


        if (userInfo.length > 0){
            var picInfo = userInfo.filter((value) =>{
                return value.uid == uid
            })[0].uid
            //})[0].data.photoURL

            
    
    
    
            
         
            return picInfo

        }
        else {
            return 'null'
        }
    }

    function getDisplayName(uid){

        //return JSON.stringify(userInfo[0])

        
        return userInfo.length
     
    
        if (userInfo.length > 0){
            var nameInfo = userInfo.filter((value) =>{
                return value.uid == uid
            })[0].uid
            //})[0].data.displayName


            console.log("this is the display name" + nameInfo)




            return nameInfo
        }
        else {
            return 'null'
        }


    }
    
    

    function signOutUser(){
        auth.signOut().then(() => {
            navigation.replace('Login')
        })
    }


    


    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
            title: "Chats",          

            

            headerRight: () => (
                <View style={{
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    justifyContent: "space-between",
                    width: 80,
                    marginRight: 20

                }}>
                    
                <View style={{marginLeft: 20}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Profile", {currentUser: auth.currentUser})} activeOpacity={0.5}>
                        <Avatar rounded source={{ uri: auth?.currentUser?.photoURL }}/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("AddChat")}>
                        <SimpleLineIcons name="pencil" size={24} color="black"></SimpleLineIcons>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                </View>
            )

            


        });
    }, [navigation])

    function enterChat(id, chatName, photo){
        navigation.navigate("Chat", {
            id: id,
            chatName: chatName,
            photo: photo

        })
    }

    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
           
            <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
                {chats.map(({id, data, otherUser}) => (
                    <CustomListItem key={id} id={id} enterChat={enterChat} photo={getphotoUrl(otherUser)} userName={getDisplayName(otherUser)} isDm={data.isDM}/>
                ))}
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        height: "100%"
    }

})
```